Why custom css files don't work?
SharePoint has pretty limited layout editing, so I wanted to edit it with custom css.
I managed to enable their upload - instructions.
Unfortunately, I didn't get any further. I only found out in the debug mode of the browser that this file wasn't used, so it doesn't matter what I write there.
I've found various tutorials, but I'm afraid to dig into SharePoint with powershell lest I break it yet.
Please help
Thank you
